# JDBC: Does the connection break if i lose reference to the Connection object?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

If i have the following method -

```
public static void C()  {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection();

    .... // code

    return;
}
```

and i dont call `con.close()` , will the connection terminate automatically once the method returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...will the connection terminate automatically once the method returns?

No, it won't. It may or may not eventually close, but it's going to be a long time before it does, if ever. The connection class's finalizer probably closes the connection if it's open, but there are lots of situations where finalizers aren't ever run. It's *essential* to call `con.close()` explicitly.

Here's how I usually handle it (although I've factored a lot of this logic out into helpers, since this is verbose otherwise):

```
public static void C()
throws SQLException
{
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection();
    try {
        .... // code

        // done with the connection
        con.close();
        con = null;
    }
    finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // Eat it to avoid masking any exception that
                // got us here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that having detected the unclosed connection in the `finally` clause, I close it but don't allow any exception doing so may cause to get thrown. This is because the main logic closes the connection correctly, which means that if I've found an open connection in the `finally` block, an exception has already been thrown and we're handling it, so I don't want to mask that by throwing a *different* exception from `con.close()`.

With decent helpers, that gets a lot shorter and easier to write:

```
public static void C()
throws SQLException
{
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection();
    try {
        .... // code

        // done with the connection
        con = JDBCHelper.close(con);      // <== This one *allows* any exception that occurs
    }
    finally {
        con = JDBCHelper.quietClose(con); // <== This one *eats* any exception that occurs
    }
}
```

...where JDBCHelper (a hypothetical class) contains:

```
public static final Connection close(Connection con)
throws SQLException
{
    con.close();
    return null;
}

public static final Connection quietClose(Connection con)
{
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If you want a 'JDBCHelper', see Apache Commons DbUtils and DbUtils.closeQuietly() in particular. This closes the resultset/statement/connection tuple.

Comment: I look forward to Java7's Automatic Resource Management (http://wikis.sun.com/display/ProjectCoin/Proposal2009AutomaticResourceManagement) which ought to make this sort of thing much easier.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks, I figured Commons would have something, but didn't have time when doing the answer to go look (since my internal `JDBCHelper` predates Commons by...some margin :-) ).

Comment: @Donal: Ah, glad to see that that's in there. (Another link: http://docs.google.com/View?docid=dffxznxr_1nmsqkz, from http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#resourceblock) Now we just have to see whether Oracle is going to actually, you know, **do** Java 7 (the spec + RI + TCK), as they still haven't done a JSR for it. *JDK* 7 either is or is nearly feature complete (http://tech.puredanger.com/2010/06/01/java-jdk-7-plan/) despite that, which is odd and backward, but life is messy sometimes, and rarely more so when dealing with licensing disputes and acquisitions.

Answer (score 1):

It will not close immediately when the method returns. Eventually the `Connection` object will be garbage collected, and probably a finalizer will then close the connection. But there's no guarantee for when this will happen.

Don't write programs that rely on the connection being closed automatically somehow if you lose all references to the `Connection` object. Always close the connection from a `finally` block (so that it happens even in case of an exception):

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
try {
    // ... code that uses the connection
}
finally {
    // Close the connection
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: I wish it were that simple. :-) What if you're processing an exception when the `finally` block gets called, and `conn.close()` triggers a different exception? You'll end up causing the original exception to get lost, masking the real problem.

Comment: @T.J. catch the exception in the `finally` block etc., I didn't want to make this a basic Java course...

Comment: Fair enough, but in general, questioners are likely to copy what they've been given. IMV, it's important not to give them information that's sufficiently incomplete as to lead to bad patterns. Just my take.

Answer (score 0):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29

> Note: A Connection object is automatically closed when it is garbage collected. Certain fatal errors also close a Connection object.

That said, you should probably close your connections explicitly.

Comment: Which is true, but misleading; when (if ever) GC runs is nondeterminate. The OP asked if the connection was closed on return from the method.

Comment: Good clarification, my mistake to simplify things, which in this case would be dangerous ..